# How would you use node.js child processes with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js, nodes

So I have a discord bot coded in javascript that is extremely slow when interacting with the database or doing image manipulation. Is there a way to integrate it with node child processes to use more than one core and speed up the process? Currently, it takes around 30 seconds for image manipulation to complete after a command is run. Can someone please explain how would I go with implementing node child processes with canvas.js to speed up discord.js bot? Thank you

Comment: Image processing tends to be handled by asynchronous processes that wouldn’t benefit from being triggered by another layer of child processes that you manage. Maybe your image manipulation is simply slow.

Comment: Yes but I want to speed up the process. When there are multiple requests it takes ages to complete them

Comment: As I said, if you already have multiple processes, then adding a layer of processes to manage them isn't going to speed them up.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-worker-threads-pool but if it's only the image manipulation that is slow it will not speed it up. What are you using? Sharp? What manipulation are you doing?

Comment: I'm using Canvas.js